# C++: Bessel function with non-integers

Tags: c++, bessel-functions

I have been trying to find a library/function that computes the Bessel function of the first kind, but with non-integer values. 
I have the following program.

```
   // Include standard libraries
   #include <cstdlib>
   #include <cmath>
   #include <vector>
   #include <array>
   #include <iostream>


   int main(int nargs, char* args[])
   {
    std::cout << "bessel function " << jn(5./2., 1.) << "\n" ;
   }
```

However, it seems this function only calculates for integer values, so in the example I get the first Bessel function for n=2.

Anyone knows how I can determine the first Bessel function with non-integer values?

EDIT: I want to find a function in C++ that calculate J_(5/2)(x) for me.

Comment: 2+1/2 is an integer. try 2+1.0/2 instead

Comment: I have tried 2.5 too, that doesn't work either.

Comment: What is `jn()` actually?

Comment: Are you trying to call the [POSIX function](http://linux.die.net/man/3/jn) `double jn(int n, double x);`  ? If so then it is unclear why you would want to pass `2.5` to an integer parameter

Comment: Well, jn is taking only integer arguments, it seems. But I was wondering if there was a function that does take values n+1/2 for bessel functions, since I can't seem to find one.

Comment: Maybe you meant `jn(1, 2.5)` ?

Comment: No I want the Bessel function of the first kind with n=5/2.

Comment: The `j*()` and `y*()` family of functions only support the integer family of Bessel functions. [Boost Math](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/bessel/bessel_first.html) seems to have an implementation for fractionals. Including implementation details in the docs.

Comment: @chverb `n` is the order of the Bessel function. `1` means first-order, etc. There is no such thing as "2.5-th order function".

Comment: Well, it is 5/2 as order that I would like.

Answer (score 1):

`boost` library could be an answer. The Bessel function of the first kind is called `cyl_bessel_j(v, x)`. Second kind `cyl_neumann(v, x)`. Both works for real `v`.

Interesting alteranative here is the `ROOT` library from CERN with a [lot of functions](http://project-mathlibs.web.cern.ch/project-mathlibs/sw/html/group__SpecFunc.html) for scientific computation.

Comment: I looked into Boost, but all I can find for bessel function of first kind is: T bessel_jn(int n, T x, const Policy& pol)

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/special/bessel/bessel.html

Comment: I get that... But cyl_bessel_j_imp seems to check if your input is an integer:  
      if(floor(v) == v)
      {
         T r = cyl_bessel_j_imp(v, T(-x), t, pol);
         if(iround(v, pol) & 1)
            r = -r;
         return r;
      }
      else
         return policies::raise_domain_error<T>(
            function,
            "Got x = %1%, but we need x >= 0", x, pol);
   }
   
   T j, y;
   bessel_jy(v, x, &j, &y, need_j, pol);
   return j;
}